# how to read a carriage return (i.e. '\r') from a windows .txt file

Tags: c, windows, char, ascii

I know the difference between \n and \r\n. I also know that in Windows when you try read from a text file, the \r\n will be transferred into \n in your code. But what if I just want to keep the \r\n in my code for some other usage. What should I do to keep them both when read from a text file in Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode, then no translation will be made.